# Third Party WordPress ad placement plugin / utility for Yahoo APT

Tags: wordpress, yahoo, ads, apt

Is there a third-party ad placement plugin or utility for WordPress that works with Yahoo APT, or do I have to roll my own?  It looks like there are a lot of options for Adsense, but I can't seem to find anything for APT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AdRotate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adrotate/). This is not specific for AdSense, but let you define blocks that you can insert in your template.

In this blocks, you can show the adsense/yahoo/png/flash advertising that you want. It manage the rotation automatically. If there are mora than an ads in a block, it display at random!

Stats included